Terraform rancher provider "no api_url provided" error
I am running into this error with using Terraform rancher2 provider. I am using 3.1.0 since it's the only one works with harvester. It works fine if I use unaliased provider.
Error:

Error: [ERROR] Normalizing url: no api_url provided
with provider["registry.terraform.io/rancher/rancher2"],
on  line 0:
(source code not available

Calling root module:
module "cluster" {

  providers = {
    rancher2 = rancher2.southeast
  }
  source = "./terraform-rancher-cluster-install"

  # Variables
  group_name            = "group1"
  kubernetes_version    = "v1.28.8"
  project_name          = "appdevprjct"
  rancher_env           = "southeast"
}
Providers
provider "rancher2" {
  alias     = "rancher-southwest"
  api_url   = data.vault_generic_secret.terraform_rancher_southwest.data["endpoint"]
  token_key = data.vault_generic_secret.terraform_rancher_southwest.data["bearer_token"]
}

provider "rancher2" {
  alias     = "rancher-southeast"
  api_url   = data.vault_generic_secret.terraform_rancher_southeast.data["endpoint"]
  token_key = data.vault_generic_secret.terraform_rancher_southeast.data["bearer_token"]
}

#data for modules

data "vault_generic_secret" "terraform_rancher_southeast" {
  path = "terraform/rancher-southeast"
}
    
data "vault_generic_secret" "terraform_rancher_southwest" {
  path = "terraform/rancher-southwest"
}

